# Datetime column from Table1 is not matching the DateTime column from Table 2

Tags: datetime, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Hello I have an issue of matching two different datetime columns.

I need to compare the two of them (and their data), but at the moment of putting them in the same table (using a datetime relation) I do not get the match I need:

What I need:

```
| Datetime_1             | Datetime_2             |
| ----------             | ----------             |
| 01/01/2023 08:00:00 AM |                        |
  ...                      ...
| 01/11/2023 12:00:00 AM | 01/11/2023 12:00:00 AM |
| 01/11/2023 01:00:00 AM | 01/11/2023 01:00:00 AM |
  ...                     ...
| 31/01/2023 12:00:00 PM | 31/01/2023 12:00:00 PM |
```

What I get:

[image]

Datetime_1 goes from **01/01/2023 12:00:00AM to 01/31/2023 11:00:00PM** (with steps of 1h) and Datetime_2 goes from **01/11/2023 8:15:00 PM to 02/06/2023 7:45:00 PM** (with steps of 30min).

I did a relation with the two of them and I didn't receive any error:

[image]

I already put both lists in Date/Time format in Power Query and Data panel.

[image]

However, I noticed my main datetime list doesn't have the hierarchy icon on fields panel, while the secondary datetime lists have it, (but not the hour section):

[image]
[image]

Also, as I mentioned before, my list have a range between Jan and Feb. I do not understand why this range continues and match some dates on the on my main datetime list:

[image]

Comment: If that is your requirement, you need to pre-process your data to have matching timestamps.

Comment: The reason you're getting these results is that your time stamps will never line up. Yes, it let you create the join, but my guess is that is only because both fields have the same formatting. Also, it is best practices to separate your dates and time in separate date and time dimensions, then join them via a fact table. [See also here.](https://radacad.com/how-to-use-time-and-date-dimensions-in-a-power-bi-model)

Comment: @Dolunaykiz I will try your proposition, but I have multiples table and I already did a connection between one tables, and it was possible without any problem to join both tables using datetime format. Thats why I am trying to do it like this.

Comment: @Dolunaykiz Please create an answer explaing the fact table and I will mark it as a solution. I worked your proposition, thank you!!

Comment: You are quite welcome, glad it worked for you. I just turned the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, turning this into an answer. The reason you're getting these results is that your time stamps will never line up. Yes, it let you create the join, but my guess is that is only because both fields have the same formatting. Also, it is best practices to separate your dates and time in separate date and time dimensions, then join them via a fact table. [See also here.](https://radacad.com/how-to-use-time-and-date-dimensions-in-a-power-bi-model)

Answer (score 2):

**Troubleshooting**
Part of the difficulty troubleshooting this is the two columns are formatted differently. Just for now, make sure both are formatted as Long Date Time. When comparing the relationship, do not drag the hierarchy (for the one that has it) into the table but rather just the date itself. When you do, you will see the full timestamp for both columns and the issue will become more clear.

**Power BI & Relationships on DateTime**
Power BI will only match related rows if the date and time match exactly, so 4/15/2023 12:00:00 AM will not match 4/15/2023/12:00:01 AM. You mentioned one side of the relationship has 30 minute steps while the other has 1 hour steps. Power BI is not going to match up a 1:30am and 1:00am value for you. If you want that 1:30 value to match up to 1:00, create another column truncating the :30 minutes and build your relationship on the truncated column.

**Time Dimension**
I'm not sure of your application so don't know if this will work, but when dealing with time, I try to separate Date and Time into separate columns and have both a Date and Time dimension. Below is my time dimension DAX. You can generate any minute-precise interval with it. Notice the last defined column "timekey". I create a column in my fact table to relate to this key.

```
DimTime = 
var every_n_minutes = 15 /* between 0 and 60; remainders in last hourly slice */

/* DO NOT CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE */
var slice_per_hour = trunc(DIVIDE(60,every_n_minutes),0)
var rtn = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            GENERATESERIES(0, 24*slice_per_hour - 1, 1),
            "hour24", TRUNC(DIVIDE([Value],slice_per_hour),0),
            "mins", MOD([Value],slice_per_hour) * every_n_minutes
        ),
        "hour12", MOD([hour24] + 11,12) + 1,
        "asTime", TIME([hour24],[mins],0),
        "timekey", [hour24] * 100 + [mins]
    )
return rtn
```